# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108) - Automation error

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am new to VBA and this is my first ever post. Please keep this in mind when reviewing my code.

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to create a graph based on a specific range of data. I have four sheets in total that are roughly 7000 lines per sheet. Three of the four sheets are able to create a graph, however one of the sheets keeps giving me the *Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108) - Automation Error - The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.*

Across all sheets, the macro is the same except for which sheet to reference (i.e. Set we = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(*NAME OF SHEET*) ) When I tried debugging, it highlighted the **Set graphObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)** portion of the code. I do not know why it's causing a problem since the other sheets are 99% the same format, except for the sheet reference.

**CODE**

```
Sub Example_Graph()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim manpowerCell As Range
    Dim companyCell As Range
    Dim graphDataRange As Range
    Dim graphObj As ChartObject
    
    ' Set the worksheet where the data and graph will be created
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example")
    
    ' Find the "manpower" cell in column F
    Set manpowerCell = ws.Columns("F:F").Find("manpower", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' Find the "Compay" cell beneath the "manpower" cell in column F
    Set companyCell = ws.Columns("F:F").Find("Company", After:=manpowerCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' Find the rows for "MONTH", "Previous P6", "P6", and "REMAINING" next to "Company"
    Dim monthRow As Long
    Dim prevP6Row As Long
    Dim p6Row As Long
    Dim remainingRow As Long
    
    monthRow = companyCell.Offset(1, 1).Row
    prevP6Row = companyCell.Offset(3, 1).Row
    p6Row = companyCell.Offset(4, 1).Row
    remainingRow = companyCell.Offset(6, 1).Row
    
    ' Set the graph data range to include only the required rows
    Dim startCol As Long
    Dim endCol As Long
    
    startCol = ws.Cells(monthRow, "X").Column
    endCol = ws.Cells(remainingRow, "BT").Column
    
    
    Set graphDataRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(monthRow, startCol), ws.Cells(remainingRow, endCol))
    
    ' Create a new chart on the same worksheet
    Set graphObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    
    ' Set the chart data source and chart type (column clustered graph)
    With graphObj.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=graphDataRange
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered ' Set to column clustered graph
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "6-Month Period Column Clustered Graph for Company"
        ' Customize other chart properties as needed
    End With
End Sub
```

**What I tried**

Originally when I first ran the code, it created a graph. However, when I tried adjusting the dimensions to make a larger graph, it gave the error. I then tried undoing the changes I made by setting it to the original dimensions, however it gave the error again and not a graph that it had originally created. I am lost on how to debug this type of problem.

Comment: I can't see an obvious reason for the error.  One thing you should do when using `FIND` though is check something was found.  Check that `IF Not manpowerCell Is Nothing THEN` before allowing the code to continue.

Comment: Hey! I just reopened my workbook and it ran perfectly. I was about to implement your suggestion, however when I tried test running it before that, it had created a graph. However, now another sheet that did not give me the run-time error I posted about, is now giving me the error. I wonder if it has to do with the amount of charts created?

Comment: I think you're only limited by memory on how many charts you can have.  You can find the specs here:  [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).  Charts are the third section from the bottom.

Comment: Hey! Very helpful website! I read over the chart section and tried changing the chart type in my code and it gave the error that it's only limited to 255. I think the problem was memory limitations. Thanks for the help